# prototype for "..." does not match any in class "..."

Tags: c++, qt

господа! у меня ещё такой вопрос: По примеру из книги по программированию на Qt и C++, написал программу, которая, методом графического представления(QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsItem), должна отображать маленькую окружность и картинку(QPixmap), которая является потомком окружности и четыре кнопки, которые позволяют уменьшать, увеличивать, и поворачивать изображение. Результатом компиляции вылетают 2 ошибки:
1)prototype for 'myView::myView(QWidget*)' does not match any in class 'myView'
 myView::myView(QWidget *parent)

2)candidates are: myView::myView(const myView&)
 class myView : public QGraphicsView

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться, что это за ошибки и как их устранить. Заранее спасибо!

Вот код:

файл main.cpp

```
#include "myview.h"
#include <QApplication>

class SimpleItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
private:
    enum{nPenWidth = 3};

public:
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        QPointF ptPosition(-10 - nPenWidth, -10 - nPenWidth);
        QSizeF size(20 + nPenWidth * 2, 20 + nPenWidth * 2);
        return QRectF(ptPosition, size);
    }

    virtual void paint(QPainter* ppainter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)
    {
        ppainter->save();
        ppainter->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, nPenWidth));
        ppainter->drawEllipse(-10, -10, 20, 20);
        ppainter->restore();
    }

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
        QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(pe);
    }

    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(pe);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget wgt;

    //Создаём сцену и задаём ей параметры
    QGraphicsScene scene(QRectF(-100, -100, 640, 480));

    //Задаём область отображения сцены и создаём кнопки
    myView* pView = new myView(&scene);
    QPushButton* pcmdZoomIn = new QPushButton("Zoom &In");
    QPushButton* pcmdZoomOut = new QPushButton("Zoom &Out");
    QPushButton* pcmdRotateLeft = new QPushButton("Rotate &Left");
    QPushButton* pcmdRotateRight = new QPushButton("Rotate &Right");

    //Устанавливаем сглаживание нарисованной фигуры
    pView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    //Добавляем фигуру в сцену
    SimpleItem* pSimpleItem = new SimpleItem;
    scene.addItem(pSimpleItem);
    pSimpleItem->setPos(0, 0);
    pSimpleItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    //Добавляем картинку в сцену
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* pPixmapItem = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("../101res/img/png/image.png"));
    pPixmapItem->setParentItem(pSimpleItem);
    pPixmapItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    //Задаём действия кнопкам
    QObject::connect(pcmdZoomIn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pView, SLOT(ZoomIn()));
    QObject::connect(pcmdZoomOut, SIGNAL(clicked()), pView, SLOT(ZoomOut()));
    QObject::connect(pcmdRotateLeft, SIGNAL(clicked()), pView, SLOT(Left()));
    QObject::connect(pcmdRotateRight, SIGNAL(clicked()), pView, SLOT(Right()));

    //Задаём расположение объектов
    QVBoxLayout* pvbl = new QVBoxLayout;
    pvbl->addWidget(pView);
    pvbl->addWidget(pcmdZoomIn);
    pvbl->addWidget(pcmdZoomOut);
    pvbl->addWidget(pcmdRotateLeft);
    pvbl->addWidget(pcmdRotateRight);

    wgt.setLayout(pvbl);

    wgt.setWindowTitle("События сцены");

    wgt.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

файл myview.cpp

```
#include "myview.h"

myView::myView(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

myView::~myView()
{

}
```

файл myview.h

```
#ifndef MYVIEW_H
#define MYVIEW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets>

class myView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myView(QGraphicsScene *pScene, QWidget* parent = 0)
        : QGraphicsView(pScene, parent)
    {
    }
    ~myView();

public slots:
    void ZoomIn()
    {
        scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }

    void ZoomOut()
    {
        scale(1/1.1, 1/1.1);
    }

    void Left()
    {
        rotate(-5);
    }

    void Right()
    {
        rotate(5);
    }
};

#endif // MYVIEW_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй из `myview.cpp` удалить эти строки:

```
myView::myView(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
}
```

Чтоб осталось только это:

```
#include "myview.h"

myView::~myView()
{

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Не думал, что всё окажется на столько просто!!! )))